# Offline support options for Jxbrowser

Tags: progressive-web-apps, jxbrowser

I am launching a react application launching within jxbrowser 6.20 build on top of create react app. I would like to add offline support. Use localStorage or use serviceWorkers ?

Comment: What will be the main function you want to implement? Not limited to caching requests, you can perform push notifications and periodic background syncs using service workers while `localStorage` is the simplest way to store key-value pairs of data on the browser(web storage).

Comment: Will service workers on create-react-app functionally work the same way as chrome browser ?